# How to open gmail app, not message send screen?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gmail

I want to open my gmail application on button click. Everywhere it shows how to send messages via gmaial using `Intent.ACTION_SEND`. But I don't want to send message. Instead I just want to launch my gmail app and see my messages list. How can I do it? Maybe I have to find the package name and laucnh the app, or there is another better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your Answer

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm");
if (launchIntent != null) {
    startActivity(launchIntent);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, "There is no Gmail App available in android", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```